# Как написать модуль вызывающий события с возможностью повесить обработчики на nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Подкиньте ссылку с туториалом, где описано создание модуля с классом
при вызове модуля создается новый объект на события которого можно вешать обработчики

сколько гуглю, но пока натыкаюсь только на самые примитивные статьи, и простого модуля с нужным функционалом не могу найти, чтоб код подсмотреть.

Comment: вы бы задачу конкретизировали, а то какой-то сферический конь в вакууме получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Node.js EventEmitter Tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-eventemitter-tutorial.html)
- [Emitting Custom Events in Node.js](http://venodesigns.net/2011/04/16/emitting-custom-events-in-node-js/)
- [Руководство по EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Вот простейший пример модуля, экспортирующего класс, который генерирует события каждые `n` миллисекунд.

```
var events = require('events');
exports.sampleEventer = function(interval, caller_name){
    this.interval = interval;
    this.caller_name = caller_name;
    this.goForvard = function(){
        var me = this;

        setInterval(function() {
            me.emit('some_event', me.caller_name);
        }, me.interval);

    }
}
exports.sampleEventer.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
```